# Is there a way for me to trigger the in-app purchase in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, orientation

I'm working on an iOS game that's always in landscape mode.

When I test in-app purchases on the simulator, however, the purchase vc comes up in portrait mode.

This would be wonky since the User would have to rotate the phone and the view behind the in-app purchase is still in landscape.

**Is there a way for me to trigger the in-app purchase in landscape mode?**

Here's a screenshot of what's happening...

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code from my app delegate setting landscape...

```
var allowedOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .landscape

public func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return allowedOrientation
}
```

Here's how the purchase is triggered...

```
func purchase(_ product: Product) {
    guard SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() else { return }

    self.productBeingPurchased = product
            
    guard !isTesting, let p = products.first(where: {
        $0.productIdentifier == product.id
    }) else { return }
    
    let payment = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}
```

Comment: purchase vc comes in portrait?  isn't it your own viewcontroller and you in full control of how you present it?

Comment: what about game in iPad in landscape mode?

Comment: It's only for iPhone right now, and no I don't own the VC. My app delegate tells everything to be in landscape only, but the payment is presented by apple.